# How connect from IPad to a local network NodeJS Server?

Tags: node.js, ipad, local-network

I'd like to connect to a running NodeJS Server installed on my Windows OS System from my IPad using the local network.

Is there any way to connect this or other devices in the local network?

I'm currently using xip.io but I didn't get any result.

Comment: yes... what happens when you try?

Comment: Yes, that is possible and there are many ways to do so.  This question is far too broad to even know where to start.  Maybe start with describing the actual problem you're trying to solve (what your app intends to do) and what type of app you're looking for on the iPad (web app?  native app?)?

Comment: I have a **NodeJS** server that serves _static pages_ on my local machine, but that I need is to connect to that server from the IPad browser within the _same local network_. Is possible or I need any software to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using the next steps:

1. Install the following NPM Package - [**Minihost**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minihost) globally using `npm install -g minihost`. It may require the [**graceful-fs**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graceful-fs) package update.
2. I create a **server.js** file with the next sample code:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const path = require("path");
    //const minihost = require("minihost");

    const server = express();

    const host = process.env.host || "127.0.0.1";
    const port = process.env.port || 2000;

    server.set('views', './app/views');
    server.set('view engine', 'jade');

    server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    server.use(bodyParser.json());

    server.get("/", (req, res) => res.render("home"));
    server.listen(port, host, () => console.log(`Listening on http://${host}:${port}`))
```

3. Create the view `app\views\home.jade` with some sample code.
4. Execute the next command in your CLI interface:

```
    h -- node server.js //Don't forget prefix with h -- your node server command
```

5. Execute, if you are in Windows OS Machine the cmd command `ipconfig` to get the IP of your local machine.
6. Put in your device the next URL:

   http://node-xip-io.YOUR-LOCAL-IP.xip.io:2000 //i.e. http://node-xip-io.192.168.0.102.xip.io:2000

> Don't forget replace **YOUR-LOCAL-IP** with the IP you got with the `ipconfig` cli command.